# ProximityDevice not finding Sony RC-S380 NFC Reader/Writer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10, nfc

I got my hands on an RC-S380 NFC Reader/Writer, however after installing the drivers from Sony, the Device shows up in Device Manager as an "NFC Port" and not a "Proximity Device".

In my application, ProximityDevice.GetDefault() is returning null.

How can I get it to be recognized as a ProximityDevice?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue : with an old driver (5.3.9.2) it was recognized as Proximity Device.

Since the 5.5.0.6, it's no longer considered as Proximity Device *by default*.

I found a way to fix this : once the driver is installed, go to Control Panel  > NFC Port/PaSoRi

Check the "Enable NFP" box at the bottom of the windows, apply, then unplug and plug back the reader, the device is now responding as a Proximity Device

Best

Alex

Comment: Thank you! thank you! thank you! This did it for me. This should be marked as the answer!